# AdapterViewFlipper not showing dynamic images

Tags: android, android-image

I am using AdapterViewFlipper, it shows images from resources but when I tried to load dynamic images from url its not showing anything.

//wokring

```
holder.flipper_image_view.setImageResource(R.drawable.app_icon_small);
```

//not working

```
imageLoader.loadImage(imageUrl.trim(),
                options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String s, View view) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        holder.flipper_image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingCancelled(String s, View view) {

                    }
            });
```

I have checked there is image on the url and its opening in browser easily also working with simple Imageview. Please suggest.

Comment: did you set imageview object in imageLoader.

Comment: Yes. I have set it. You can see it in onLoadingComplete callback.

Comment: show me your url and did you check its throwing any error? put log in onLoadingFailed and onLoadingCancelled and check its showing any error

Comment: Url is working fine, as mentioned its working with simple ImageView. In logs image getting download properly not throwing any error.                             URL Is : http://jjss.weblogicx.in/Images/AdvertImages/20310201735074.jpg , http://jjss.weblogicx.in/Images/AdvertImages/20310201734918.jpg

Comment: did you check onLoadingFailed and onLoadingCancelled?

Comment: Checked. not there. Image getting download successfully. Below are logs.       D/ImageLoader: Start display image task [http://jjss.weblogicx.in/Images/AdvertImages/20310201734918.jpg_1080x1776]
 D/ImageLoader: Load image from disk cache [http://jjss.weblogicx.in/Images/AdvertImages/20310201734918.jpg_1080x1776]
 D/ImageLoader: Display image in ImageAware (loaded from DISC_CACHE) [http://jjss.weblogicx.in/Images/AdvertImages/20310201734918.jpg_1080x1776]

Comment: Use NetworkImageView and set imageLoader there

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
NetworkImageView networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbImageUrl);
RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new BitmapLruCache(BitmapLruCache.getDefaultLruCacheSize()));

networkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, imageLoader);
```

And this is BitmapLruCache.java

```
public class BitmapLruCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements ImageCache {

    public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        return cacheSize;
    }

    public BitmapLruCache() {
        this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
    }

    public BitmapLruCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
        super(sizeInKiloBytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
    }}
```

Comment: Thanks dear, but for this I need to add Volley in my project. So I replaced AdapterViewFlipper with ViewFlipper and its working fine.